# Are arbitration agreements subject to a 6 year statute of limitations in NJ?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, new-jersey, arbitration, statute-of-limitations

Generally, breach of contract in New Jersey must be filed within six years of the date the cause of action accrues.

Does this apply to enforcement of arbitration agreements?

Comment: Keep in mind that the cause of action accrues when the arbitration agreement is breached not when it is entered into or when the dispute between the parties to be arbitrated arises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are arbitration agreements subject to a 6 year statute of limitations in NJ?

Yes. Remember the precedents from NJ that [I cited in response to one of your recent posts](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/86807/18505):

> a state may not "*subject an arbitration agreement to more burdensome requirements than those governing the formation of other contracts*"

This implies that the statute of limitations for arbitration agreements is the same as for contracts in general. If it were otherwise, that departure would constitute a greater burden on whichever party happens to oppose the enforcement of the arbitration agreement.